# android connection exception/lost manager

Tags: java, android, code-injection

**Background**

So I've inherited an android application that in various places connects to web services to send or receive information.

As it is right now, when a connection fails the user of the android device is prompted with an error message that for most users are viewed as obscure.

**The problem**

So what I'm looking for is a pattern or suggestion on how to implement a solution in this android application that catches all java connection exceptions and presents a dialog telling the user he lost the internet connection and needs to try again.

Any ideas? :-)

**Edit, current idea**

My current idea to solve this issue, or making it a bit more managed instead of having a fractured exception handling that takes care of the problem at every possible connection is this.
Each communication instance/class will inherit from a super class, or implement an interface that forces this class to be used. This class contains the logic for connection exceptions. Lets just for now call it ConnectionExceptionManager.
The problem then only becomes implementation of this in each communication class in each web service call. In each web service calls exception I need to check for communication exceptions and if it hits, use the ConnectionExceptionManager in this catch.

This would however still make it a hassle, to copy into request method in each communication class.

Any ideas about improving this current idea of mine?

Comment: handle each and every connection related exception and create dialog boxes in that handler code for appropriate exception, e.g. If device lost internet connection then give appropriate error message to user and also you can check that whether device has internet connection or not before proceeding..

Comment: This is probably what I will have to do, but I'd like not to do it that way. I want it managed, not fractured.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you need to check internet connectivity before performing any internet related action. For that you can simply create public static boolean function i.e. public static boolean isInternetConnected(){...} in global class so that you can reuse your function.

If you want your application to check internet connectivity automatically then you can use [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which will work in background and in its protected abstract void onHandleIntent (Intent intent) you can check isInternetConnected() returns true and if not then you can open AlertDialog.

To use this background service after repeated intervals while application is running, you can use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is not to check internet connectivity, it is to manage the exceptions that can come from losing it. Like when a user starts to download a lot of data it can take a bit of time and if the connection fails during this download or another download or articles the user should get a good error message. Perhaps it looks like I'm lazy now, and that's because I am. I dont want to try and find every connection that has a longer download and implement the same code. I want to manage the failed connections, feels like that would be the propper OOP way to handle my problem.